# Timeout exception if custom method still runs after define time

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement custom functionality that can work as monitor any method for a timeout after a certain time. for example, if A() is taking more time than define time then it should throw an exception for the timeout process.

```
function A(){
// Do Something
}
```

But at the same time I don't want to add or modify any code inside the A() function, I mean there should be something custom Annotation on top of the A() function which should monitor its execution time asynchronous and throw an exception after defined time as well as stop A() function execution.

I know inside of function with StopWatch class library I can achieve this, but not sure how to do this outside of A() function.

Development environment: Visual Studio 2019, Dot NET Core 5.0

Comment: Id C# 4.0 really your *limit*? What version of Visual Studio (if any)? In what context is this code executed? What kind of application?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 and dot net core

Comment: I could think of writing wrapper functions each running `Task.Run` with a timeout (getting it from a custom attribute you write) and managing error result. But stopping function execution without changing its code... don't know... this could generate loads of problems (think writing data into a file or in database)

Comment: Thanks, @Marco, I have implemented it in the same manner, but the requirement is different to create some custom annotation that can handle the above scenario so that it can apply to any method in the application.

Comment: @Jimi, About the ```CancellationTokenSource``` can we apply this as like annotation?

Comment: Annotations have display and validation roles. But with, e.g., a custom `TypeDescriptionProvider` you could do that. -- Not if you're actually using C# 4.0, you'd need a NuGet package that extends the functionality.

Comment: You can't stop an arbitrary thread from running without co-operative cancellation unless you use `Thread.Abort()` which is almost always a really bad idea (and has in fact been removed altogether from .Net 5 where calling it will throw `PlatformNotSupportedException`).

Comment: @Jimi, do you have any working reference for this with NuGet package

Comment: The NuGet package I'm referring to is related to C# 4.0 and async/await. You still haven't specified whether C# 4.0 is a real requirement, for some reason. -- There's no `.Net Core 5`, there's `.Net 5`. .Net Core stopped at version `3.1`. -- I don't see how C# 4.0 can be a requirement with `.Net 5`. -- You should also specify if *Annotations* means `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` or something else. -- The type of Application is also still missing.

Comment: The framework requirement is ```.net 5```, and when I am saying _Annotation_ it means it should like we have _Annotations_ in ```System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations``` so that we can add that functionality on any existing method also.

Comment: @H.S - Real code is always a good idea. `function A() { // Do Something }` isn't valid C#.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
if(!Task.Run(MyMethod).Wait(myTimeout)){
    throw new MyTimeoutException()
}
```

This will run an arbitrary method on another thread, and throw an exception if the timeout is exceeded. But the method will continue to run in the background until it completes.

The better alternative is to change your methods to accept a cancellationToken and call [`ThrowIfCancellationIsRequested()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=net-5.0) frequently. You can then use [CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time) to create a token that is cancelled after some time. I would say that accepting a cancellationtoken (and some way to report progress) is probably a good idea for all methods that take a significant amount of time.

There is no good way to do non-cooperative cancellation since it becomes difficult to reason about the program state. If an exception is generated on the thread, should it be possible to catch the exception? If it can be caught it can just be ignored. If not, there is a risk that resources are not correctly disposed.

Comment: _"But at the same time I don't want to add or modify any code inside the A() function"_ seems a requirement to me. That's why I only posted a comment, telling the OP that this approach could lead to loads of problems...

Comment: @Marco I would argue that *your requirements are unreasonable, do it this way instead* is also an answer.  Perhaps not the desired answer, but still an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<int> observable =
    Observable
        .Start(() => A())
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));

IDisposable subscription =
    observable
        .Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                /* A() completed successfully */
                /* x has value */
            },
            ex =>
            {
                /* A() timed out */
                /* ex has exception */
            });
```

Or this:

```
IObservable<int> observable =
    Observable
        .Amb(
            Observable.Start(() => A()),
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)).Select(x => -1));

IDisposable subscription =
    observable
        .Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                /* x is value from A() or -1 if timed out */
            });
```

You asked for this:

> as well as stop `A()` function execution

Well, you can't do that. Once the code starts, unless it already has a mechanism for terminating early, you can't stop it.

Comment: Pardon for my questions, but I have some doubt. If the observable ends with a timeout, is called function terminated automatically? This is one of OP requests. Second, it seemed to me that OP didn't want to write more code, but let the original functions annotated so they have new behaviour when called...

Comment: @Marco - If the original function cannot be modified then it can't be stopped unless it already has a way to do that.

Comment: I definitely agree with you

Comment: It's seems like I have chane some approach, as well as, let me try @Enigmativity code.